# Angular js tags not working on tomcat 8

Tags: angularjs, tomcat

I have web  application with html/js files using angular js. The war file was deployed in tomcat 6 and was working fine. Now that I need to move it to  new server with tomcat 8 on it, I am  not able to see angular js stuff working on it. I tried removing ng-model in my input tag and its working good (though its only  in one page), but I need all the angular js stuff to work. Is there any configuration or trick I am   missing out in my new environment.

Comment: what is the extension of the file .html / .jsp you used ?

Comment: No there is not any configuration. Make sure that assets are being loaded when you run application.

Comment: @UsmanRana: can you please elaborate your point